# Is there a way to make font awesome icons look thinner/slimmer using CSS?

Tags: css, font-awesome

I am trying to make the font awesome icons look slimmer https://jsfiddle.net/cliffeee/7L6ehw9r/1/ .

I tried using the '-webkit-text-stroke' but that didn't help when hovering over the icons, because you can see the background color, which I don't want it to be seen.

```
.accordion-toggle {
  background-color: #777;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;

}

.collapsed, .accordion-toggle:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}

.accordion-toggle:after {
-webkit-text-stroke: 2px #eee; //  Icons thinner not working 
    font-family: 'FontAwesome'; /* essential to enable caret symbol*/
    content: "\f067";
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 30px;



}

.collapsed:after {
 content: "\f068";
}

.collapse {
  padding: 0 18px;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

Comment: You're talking about font-weight right?

Comment: you can handle this with `font-size` but it's not a suitable solution and change your icon with different icon (thin and smooth). for example check `https://icomoon.io/app/` and different icon packs

Comment: you can use font awesome PRO :) which has other versions of the icons compared to the free one including `light` version. Have a look here for the "+" sign for example: https://fontawesome.com/icons/plus?style=solid

Comment: Hi@cornel.raiu, in fact font awesome pro icons is what I wanted to have, but it didn’t work in my CSS. As you can see, I've used the same unicode that’s mentioned in the link you shared, but that didn’t make my icons thinner. Is there a way to have font awesome PRO icons in CSS

Answer (score 0):

Just remove font-weight:bold in ur css ,

Comment: Hi @Mahesh, this just increases  and decrease the font size of icons, but doesn’t  make them look slimmer.

Comment: U mean thickness of text ? or size slimmer means?

Comment: thickness of the text.

Comment: I am trying to reduce the thickness of the plus size here. Could you look at this? snack.expo.io/@lindapaiste/022490

Answer (score 0):

no you can not make font awesome icons look slimmer but the `+` icon you are using was already a default thickness of font awesome.

you are applying `font-weight: bold;` in `.accordion-toggle:after` class. make it `font-weight: normal;` it will change your icon to the normal thickness.

you can increase the thickness of font awesome by applying `font-weight: bold;` but you cant decrease it using `font-weight: lighter;`.

Thank You...

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do. just remove font awesome and add your custom text, symbol whatever you need in css content property.

Please try below CSS.

```
 .accordion-toggle:after {
  /*-webkit-text-stroke: 2px #eee; */ /*remove it*/
  /* font-family: 'FontAwesome'; */ /* remove it*/
   content: "+"; /*change*/
   color: white;
   font-weight: bold; /*remove it or change value according to you*/
   float: right;
   margin-left: 5px;
   margin-right: 30px;
}

 .collapsed:after {
  content: "-";
 }
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Prakash, I would like to use font awesome to do this. Thank you.

Comment: Hello @cliff, Ok great. Then you can do using font awesome 5 pro icons (https://fontawesome.com/icons/plus?style=light)..... note - font awesome 5 pro required license. If you are ok with it then fine otherwise you can use alternate that i have given you. -- Thanks :)

Comment: We can't use this in react native, can we? I am trying to reduce the thickness of the plus size here. Could you look at this? snack.expo.io/@lindapaiste/022490

Comment: hello @Jnl , please check - https://snack.expo.io/@prakashrajotiya/shallow-watermelons